# useRef() does not redraw the value

Tags: reactjs

I have a useRef hook and two components. In one component, I increase the value on click by 1 unit, and in the second component, I draw the value. I pass the value itself through useContext.

Now the problem is that the value is not being redrawn. How can this be fixed?

```js
export const ContactContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const countItem = useRef(1);

  const value = { countItem };

  return (
    <ContactContext.Provider value={value}>
        <div>
          <AddValue />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Logo />
        </div>
    </ContactContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```js
const AddValue = () => {
  const { countItem } = useContext(ContactContext);

  const addItemHandler = () => {
    countItem.current = countItem.current + 1;
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={addItemHandler}
        >
          <img src="plus.svg" alt="plus logo" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
function Logo() {
  const { countItem } = useContext(ContactContext);

  return (
    <p data-testid="statistics">
      {`Count of channels: ${countItem.current}`} <br />
    </p>
  );
}
```

Comment: Changing the ref value will to cause a re-render. If you want your component to re-render use state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useRef wont cause components in React to rerender

```
function App() {
  const [countItem, setCountItem] = useState(1)

  const value = { countItem, setCountItem };
```

In AddValue

```
const AddValue = () => {
  const { countItem, setCountItem } = useContext(ContactContext);

  const addItemHandler = () => {
   setCountItem(c => c +1)
  };
```

Reading the new React [docs for state management](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-a-components-memory#when-a-regular-variable-isnt-enough) will help
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Replace `useRef` with `useState`.
`useRef` update the value but does not rerender.